# How to detect collisions of two canvas object Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I am developing easy space invaders clone game and i need to figure out a way how to detect collision of the bullet and the alien when i shoot. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pygame in place of Tkinter (eventually in place of Canvas) - there are functions to check collisions.

To check collision you have to get position both elements and check distance between them:

a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> = c<sup>2</sup>

`a = x1 - x2`  , `b = y1 - y2` , `c = distance between objects A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2)`

If distance is smaller then some value then you have collision - distance doesn't have to be zero to have collision. This way you check collision in circle around object.

But you can check collision in square area around the object - it wil be easer for you to calculate it

Object `A (x1,y1)` has square area `x1-10 ... x1+10, y1-10 ... y1+10`. You have to check whether object `B (x2,y2)` is in that square.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a coordinates check with tkinter's [bbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method) this returns 4 tuples, x1, y1, x2, y2 , which are the top left and bottom right points of the object. with a little math, check they are not in their same space and prevent them from going in or whatever your desired effect is when they meet.

Things that might also help during your math are

tkinter's find_overlapping. which returns a tuple of the intruding your items space.

tkinter's find_enclosed. which returns a tuple of items completly enclosed.

tkinter's find_closest. which provides a cool barrier for your item.

and a lot more great words that will help you in the link posted in this post. Unfortunatly i am too low reputation to put more than one link...

checking print((canvas.bbox(item)) in python 3 helps if you want to check the tuples manually or print it in a label or such.