# Interacting balls with tkinter-canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I was able to programm some moving balls with tkinter. I used two different colors. Now I want that the white balls change the color to red if they hit a red ball. Can someone help me out?

(An extra but not so important point would be, that if the one ball hits a other ball that they change direction, it should be random which direction, but this is not so important)

All over all I have a problem to figure out, how the balls can interact with eachother. Here is my code so for:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 500

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="black")
tk.title("Drawing")
canvas.pack()

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'magenta',
          'dodgerblue', 'turquoise', 'grey', 'gold', 'pink']

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.size = random.randrange(5, 10)
        #color = random.choice(colors)
        self.xpos = random.randrange(0,WIDTH)
        self.ypos =random.randrange(0,HEIGHT)
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(self.xpos-self.size, self.ypos -self.size,self.xpos +self.size,self.ypos+self.size, fill=color)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(-5, 5)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(-5, 5)

    def update(self):
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.speedx, self.speedy)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if pos[2] >= (WIDTH) or (pos[0] ) <= 0:
            self.speedx *= -1
        if pos[3] >= (HEIGHT) or (pos[1]) <= 0:
            self.speedy *= -1


ball_list = []
Infiziert_list =[]
for i in range(100):
    ball_list.append(Ball('white'))
for j in range(3):
    ball_list.append(Ball('red'))
while True:
    for ball in ball_list:
        ball.update()
    tk.update()
    #time.sleep(0.001)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect collisions of two canvas object Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713228/how-to-detect-collisions-of-two-canvas-object-tkinter)

Comment: First: Thank you very much, but not really because i don't know how i get it in the code i have. So I need to implement it somehow in the update thingi, but from the pos i get just a vector with 3 points back. So for each ball individuell. So i don't know how to connect position ball1 to all the other balls

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like the code below.

If you want to write your own code. A good references is here, check the [Ball collisions](http://predicate.us/journey/asteroids/4/) part.

Run this code for a complete working example of colliding balls that change colour when they collide.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Balls:
    color = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"]    
    v1x,v2x,v1y,v2y=0.1*random.randint(-10, 10),0.1*random.randint(-10, 10),0.1*random.randint(-10, 10),0.1*random.randint(-10, 10)
    def __init__(self, canvas,R,x1,y1,x2,y2):
        self.R=R
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1=y1
        self.x2=x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.ball1 = canvas.create_oval(self.x1-self.R, self.y1-self.R,self.x1+self.R,self.y1+self.R, fill=random.choice(self.color))
        self.ball2 = canvas.create_oval(self.x2-self.R, self.y2-self.R,self.x2+self.R,self.y2+self.R, fill=random.choice(self.color))


    def callback(self):
        color=["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"] 
        self.AA=canvas.create_oval(self.x-10, self.y-10,self.x+10,self.y+10, fill=random.choice(color))
        self.vx,self.vy=0.5*random.randint(-10, 10),0.5*random.randint(-10, 10)
        canvas.move(self.AA, self.vx,self.vy)



    def move_balls(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.ball1, self.v1x,self.v1y)
        self.canvas.move(self.ball2, self.v2x,self.v2y)
        self.canvas.after(5, self.move_balls)

    def eventt(self):            
        A=[(canvas.coords(self.ball1)[0]-canvas.coords(self.ball2)[0]),
           (canvas.coords(self.ball1)[1]-canvas.coords(self.ball2)[1])]
        if ((A[0])**2+(A[1])**2)**0.5<=2*self.R:
            self.v1x,self.v1y,self.v2x,self.v2y=self.v2x,self.v2y,self.v1x,self.v1y
            canvas.itemconfig(self.ball1,fill=random.choice(self.color)) 
            canvas.itemconfig(self.ball2,fill=random.choice(self.color))
        if canvas.coords(self.ball1)[0]<=0 or canvas.coords(self.ball1)[2]>=400:
            self.v1x=-self.v1x
        if canvas.coords(self.ball1)[1]<=0 or canvas.coords(self.ball1)[3]>=400:
            self.v1y=-self.v1y
        if canvas.coords(self.ball2)[0]<=0 or canvas.coords(self.ball2)[2]>=400:
            self.v2x=-self.v2x
        if canvas.coords(self.ball2)[1]<=0 or canvas.coords(self.ball2)[3]>=400:
            self.v2y=-self.v2y
        self.canvas.after(10,self.eventt)


# initialize root Window and canvas
root = Tk()
root.title("Balls")
root.resizable(False,False)
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 400)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", Balls.callback)
canvas.pack()

# create two ball objects and animate them
ball = Balls(canvas ,20, 100, 200, 200, 300)
ball.move_balls()
ball.eventt()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i still don't know how I can do it with for example 50 white balls and 3 red balls. I tried now for a long time, with also the hint you gave me. But I can't come to an efficient solution.              Maybe I say again the important points: At the beginning I want to have 50 white balls and 3 red ones. If the white balls hit the red ones they should turn red. If any ball hits another ball the should move to a random direction.  And it would be nice if i don't need to initialize everyball by its own :/